# How to check fire mode in hardcore?

Tags: battlefield-3

Obviously in hardcore mode there is no HUD, so I cannot check fire mode there. But are there any visual indicators on the weapons themselves which would hint that?

Comment: I hate that too. Good thing to know is btw that the AN is always on Burst when you spawn, even if you had it on Full Auto at death. Drives me crazy :D.

Comment: That's the point of Hardcore mode

Comment: @IbrahimSwaiss: No, the point of hardcode more is to make it more realistic. In real life you have fire mode switch close to the trigger and you can clearly see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the only way to check it is to shoot your weapon. Or you can memorize it if you switch it.